# How do I customize the Laravel registration form error message?

Tags: laravel

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'last_name'  => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email'      => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users'],
        'phone'      => ['required', 'unique:users'],
        'password'   => ['required', 'string', 'min:6']
    ]);
}
```

I am sending the member form via Ajax. I want to show a custom message when I receive an error message.

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'first_name.required' => 'A title is required'
    ];
}
```

I tried the functions of these messages but it didn't work. Is there another way? Thanks. My English is bad, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the messages array as 3rd parameter in Validator::make method. Like following:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'last_name'  => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email'      => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users'],
        'phone'      => ['required', 'unique:users'],
        'password'   => ['required', 'string', 'min:6']
    ], [
        'first_name.required' => 'A title is required'
    ]
    );
}
```